# Ant design ошибка в элементе upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fileupload, ant-design

У меня есть код, в котором при выборе файла, должно загружаться фото и на основе этого показываться сообщение, но при загрузке фото, у меня всегда выдается ошибка `request.js:97 POST http://localhost:3000/profile 404 (Not Found)`. Т.е статус файла всегда 'error'

Вот код моей формы

```
let ProfileInfo = (props) => {

  const onPhotoSelected = (info) => {
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      props.setPhoto(info.file.originFileObj)
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully`);
    } else if (info.file.status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  }

  const content = (
    <Upload
      name='file'
      maxCount={1}
      onChange={onPhotoSelected}>
      <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload Photo</Button>
    </Upload>

  )

  return (
    <div 
       <Popover placement="bottom" content={content} trigger="hover">
         <img src={props.profile.photos.large} alt="profile" />
       </Popover>
    </div>
  )
}
```